# In the Careers Job Search page, add an automated search agent/email

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, jobs

I would like the Careers Job Search page to automatically email me when there is a new job that fits specific criteria I set.

The benefit is I will not have to manually search every day.

http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs

Most other job boards have this feature.  At Dice its called a "Search Agent".  At Glassdoor its called a "Job Alert".  At Indeed its called "Get new jobs for this search by email".

Since the other job boards have this feature it would make sense that we have this too.

Answer (score 5):

We've had several conversations about this very feature. It's currently in the pipeline, but I'm afraid I can't give a more specific estimate than that. But it *is* on our radar.

Answer (score 1):

It's a good idea. I've just upvoted it. I'm just surprised no one brought it up before (or perhaps more likely, this is a duplicate question, and we just haven't searched the meta site with the right keywords to be able to find it).

In any case, I realize this wasn't the question you were asking, but until that feature is implemented, you could try adapting some of the recipes/scripts from the [if-then-that](https://ifttt.com/) web site:

- [Craigslist jobs to email](https://ifttt.com/recipes/2804)
- [If new job suggestion on Linkedin, add row to spreadsheet on Google Drive](https://ifttt.com/recipes/123367)
- [StackOverflow 'Android' jobs to Google Talk](https://ifttt.com/recipes/49042) (Stackoverflow seems to have some integration issues with [IFTTT](https://ifttt.com/), and the author of that script/recipe found a workaround by using [feedrinse](http://feedrinse.com/) to do the filtering)
- etc.

This solution is not ideal, but it should work for you now as a stop-gap solution (since I'm assuming you're looking for a job now, and not necessarily x months from now for whenever StackOverflow gets to implementing it).

Answer (score 0):

This feature was implemented some time ago. We call them "job alerts". When you're viewing a list of jobs, you should see an option to save your criteria to create a job alert that will email you of new jobs that match your criteria.

[image: "create job alert" call-out]

If you click that link, you'll be able to modify your query before the alert is created.

[image: create job alert page]